# Самый лучший метод локализации фронтенда написанный на angular?

Tags: angular2, angular

Какие есть топовые и современные способы локализировать фронтендную часть? Будет 3 языка: Русский, английский, казахский

Comment: angular  в 9 версии

Comment: раньше был популярен `@ngx-translate`, но у него ограниченный функционал, в одном из приложений мне нужен был "i18n scope". Сейчас я использую `transloco`, у него очень широкий функционал. Есть вариант использовать нативный i18n через `angular/localize`, но там концепция очень проста - для каждого языка билдится приложение, нет возможности изменить язык в рантайме (нужна перезагрузка страницы), а также нужен сервер, который будет проверять `Accept-Language` заголовок либо же куки (если на клиенте при выборе другого языка будет сетиться кука `lang` например)

Comment: @overthesanity спасибо, попробуем transloco